# Can't get Authorization Code form Header in Rails Webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors

My Rails 5 app is receiving a webhook from another app.

When I do `puts params` I get all the params sent printed to my console.

But there is also an authorization code in the request. When I use requestbin I see `Authorization: 123456` in the header.

But when I print the headers to my console `puts headers` I only get:

```
{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "X-Download-Options"=>"noopen", "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies"=>"none", "Referrer-Policy"=>"strict-origin-when-cross-origin"}
```

In my application.rb I have

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*',
        :headers => :any,
        :expose  => ['Authorization'],
        :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :options, :head, :delete]
      end
    end
```

How can I get the 123456 to validate the request?

Comment: Try setting the rack-cors `credentials` option to `true` and changing the `origins` value to `true`. (The reason for changing that `origins` value is that browsers won’t allow the request from your frontend code to use credentials if the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header is the `*` wildcard. Setting the value of the rack-cors `origins` option to `true` causes rack-cors to set the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to the same value as the Origin request header, instead of the `*` wildcard.)

Comment: You need to also make sure your frontend code is setting the credentials mode for the request to `include`. For example, if your code is using XHR to make the request, set the value of `withCredentials` to `true`. Or if you’re using the Fetch API to make the request, set the `credentials` option to `include`. Or if you’re using an ajax call from a particular JavaScript library, use whatever mechanism that library provides for including credentials in the request.